# Load (or combine) several pretrained checkpoints with tf.estimator.WarmStartSettings

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I want to use pretrained weights for 2 parts of my model. I have 2 checkpoints from different models, from which I can load only one into my main model with tf.estimator.WarmStart as I'm using the estimator architecture.

```
tf.WarmStartSettings(ckpt_to_initialize_from=X)
```

[from the doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/WarmStartSettings):

> Either the directory or a specific checkpoint can be provided (in the case of the former, the latest checkpoint will be used).

I can't see how I can add an additional checkpoint. Maybe there is a way to load the weights from both checkpoint into one and load that one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `init_from_checkpoint`.

First, define assignment map:

```
dir = 'path_to_checkpoint_files'
vars_to_load = [i[0] for i in tf.train.list_variables(dir)]
```

This creates a list of all variables in checkpoints

```
assignment_map = {variable.op.name: variable for variable in tf.global_variables() if variable.op.name in vars_to_load}
```

And this creates a dict that has variables from current graph as key and variables from checkpoint as values

```
tf.train.init_from_checkpoint(dir, assignment_map)
```

This function is placed inside estimator's `model_fn`. It will override standard variable initialization.